# Is there any way to play .flv files using HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, flv

my client is very keen on playing .flv files on his website. Is there any way at all to play them? Doesn't matter if it's a dirty/hacky way.

Other similar questions are outdated.

Comment: **(1)** I think you're being down voted for lack of research. I tried _"javascript play flv"_ in **Google** and got [FLVPlayer](https://github.com/zhw2590582/FlvPlayer) and you can [test their demo](https://flvplayer.js.org/). **(2)** Basically on Stackoverflow you should ask Questions about a **programming** issue (_eg:_ code errors or crashes), then we check your code and advise you.

Answer (score 1):

There's some open-source FLV players like **[flv.js](https://github.com/Bilibili/flv.js/)**.

Your FLV must contain **H.264** video codec and **MP3** / **AAC** audio (since those codecs are supported by HTML5/browser decoders).